# enabling HTTPs on weblogic server not working

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I am trying to enable SSL on my WebLogic server but getting issues.

Here is what I've done so far:

Created custom keystore:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -dname "cn=weblogic" -alias webcenter_portal -keypass welcome1 -keystore webcenter_portal.jks -storepass changeit -validity 720
```

Created certificate for keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -v -alias webcenter_portal -keystore webcenter_portal.jks -storepass changeit -rfc -file webcenter_portal.cer
```

Imported this certificate into cacerts (JRE's trust store):

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias webcenter_portal -file C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_24/bin/webcenter_portal.cer
-keystore C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_24/jre/lib/security/cacerts
-storepass changeit
```

After this, on admin console, selected my server:

Keystores tab > selected Custom Identity and Java Standard Trust > specified keystore details > Save

SSL tab > specified keystore details. One important setting I did is 'None' in Hostname Verification.

General tab > enable SSL.

After all this configuration, I bounced my server.

However HTTPS is not working, Can anyone please guide/help where to look for problems?

Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get? Check the server log for error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is fixed now.

Based on above suggestions I enabled SSL log using -

```
-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

I could see following error after that:

```
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

After some googling I found that -keypass in keytool -genkeypair command is culprit. I didn't pass that while creating keystore and followed rest of the steps mentioned above and it worked.

Thanks.

PS: 'None' in Hostname Verification in SSL tab is not required, keep it default to BEA hostname verification.

HTH to someone.